# How to prove that $f(x, y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} \smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

In a small part of a school assignment I have to prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} \smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$:

$$f(x, y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$

I think by using the quotient rule I can prove this, since the quotient of 2 continuous functions is also a continuous function. As long as the denominator is not zero!

As silly it may be sounds, I get stuck proving that these separate functions $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are continuous functions. It is obvious that they are continuous, but I don't know how to write a good prove of functions with 2 different variables.

Comment: No it isn't take sequences $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,1/n)$ and  $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,-1/n)$ and $f(x_n,y_n) \to \pm 1$ depending on the sequence so limit isn't unique depending how your approach $(0,0)$ so $f$ isn't continuous.

Comment: @EDX $(0,0)$ isn't part of the domain OP needs to prove continuity on...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof verification: the product of two continuous functions is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901799/proof-verification-the-product-of-two-continuous-functions-is-continuous)

Comment: What book are you reading? It would be much easier to write a satisfactory answer if one knows what tools/definitions are allowed to use.

Comment: Scuse misreading, I tought your were seeking proof non-continuity at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1):

Taking any point not equal to $(0,0)$ you have $x^2+y^2$ continuous and not zero in it. Then knowing $2xy$ is continuous everywhere you divide last on former and get continuous ratio on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$.

Answering comment about $2xy$ we can consider it as product of continuous functions $f(x,y)=x, g(x,y)=y, h(x,y)=2$. Same trick works for $x^2+y^2$.

Now about continuity of $f(x,y)=x$ as function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$: inequality $|x-x_0|\leqslant \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$ gives continuity in   any $(x_0,y_0)$, as in definition of continuity we can simply consider $\varepsilon=\delta$.

Comment: "Then knowing $2xy$ is continuous..." This is OP's question: *"...I get stuck proving that these separate functions $2$ and $^2+^2$ are continuous functions."*

Comment: Just like you I know it is continuous, but my question is how to write this as a proof.

Comment: @mrsamy Obviously I need time to write answer to your comment..

Comment: @zkutch: in case you ask, I didn't vote...

Comment: @mrsamy. Thanks.

Comment: +1. Writing the polynomial as a product of projections is the standard trick to prove continuity.

Comment: +1 also for me....:-)

Comment: @zkutch Thanks a lot for your answer and your edits to it. But could you simply explain what is happening in the writing of the polynomial as a product of projections. Sounds silly but for me it looks like magic right now.

Comment: @user890995. Writing more, give me some time, pls..

Comment: @zkutch Take your time, I am already amazed by the fact that there are so many people trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First: proving that $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ is continuous. Let $(a, b)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then $|x^2 + y^2 - a^2 - b^2| = |(x + a)(x - a) + (y - b)(y + b)| \leq |x - a||x - b| + |y - b||y + b|$ by the triangle inequality. Take $(x, y)$ closer than $\delta$ to $(a, b)$. Then $|x - a|, |y - b| < \delta$, which means that also $|x + a| < \delta + 2|a|$, $|y + b| < \delta + 2|b|$ (by the triangle inequality again). So

$$|f(x, y) - f(a, b)| \leq \delta(2\delta + 2|a| + 2|b|)$$

Can you pick a $\delta$ depending only on $a, b, \epsilon$ to make this smaller than $\epsilon$?

For $2xy$, just use the product rule and that projections are continuous.

Actually, now that I think of it the product and sum rule are enough to prove that $x^2 + y^2$ is continuous as well.