# How to prove that $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} \smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$ by using the limit definition of a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

For school (real analysis) I have an assignment where a little part is about proving that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} \smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$:

$$f(x, y)=\frac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$

By using the quotient rule I want to prove this. So I get the 2 seperate functions $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$. Next I want to prove that $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are differentiable for all $a$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$ by means of the limit definition of a derivative.

For a single variable it would look something like this I think: $$\lim \limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x - a} $$ or one like this $$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ I do not know, but the part where it gets really confusing for me is how to use the limit definition of a derivative with 2 variables. Just like in my problem with the functions $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$.

So the real question is, how do I use the limit definition of a derivative to prove that $2xy$ and $x^2 + y^2$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R^2} \smallsetminus \{(0, 0)\}$?

Comment: Do you know the *definition* of derivative in the context of real functions of several variables?

Comment: Do are related  your questions with: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036137/how-to-prove-that-2xy-and-x2-y2-are-continuous-on-mathbbr2-smallse and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036014/how-to-prove-that-fx-y-frac2xyx2-y2-is-continuous-on-mathbbr2?

Comment: The title and the body of your post do no match: do you want continuity or differentiability? What is the difference between this one and the other one you asked a few minutes ago?

Comment: @mrsamy I have deleted my answer for the differentiability :-)