# Is my attempt at a proof valid?

Tags: limits, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Warning: I have no formal education in these, so sorry if my attempt is horrible.

I've recently learnt the concept behind a limit, i.e. the epsilon-delta definition and it seems really cool. I've tried to 'prove' that the product of two continuous functions is also continuous, and would like help with fixing it up by pointing out its errors.

So, with the definition of continuity being that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\ a}f(x)=f(a)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\ a}g(x)=g(a)$, I have to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\ a}f(x)g(x)=f(a)g(a)$ for all real 'a'.Here's my attempt.

By the epsilon delta definition, for all $ε_f, ε_g >0$, there must exist $_f,_g$ such that:

For $x∈(a-_f,a+_f)$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<ε_f$

For $x∈(a-_g,a+_g)$, $|g(x)-g(a)|<ε_g$.

I have set $ε'=max(ε_f,ε_g)$ and $'=max(_f,_g)$ such that for x∈(a-',a+'):

$|f(x)-f(a)|<ε'$

$|g(x)-g(x)|<ε'$

Now, I must prove that for all $ε>0$, I can find  such that for $x∈(a-,a+)$.

$|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|<ε$

$\begin{align}|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|=&|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(a)+f(x)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|\\≤&|f(x)||f(x)-f(a)|+|g(a)|g(x)-g(a)|\\<&|f(x)|ε'+|g(a)|ε'\end{align}$

I have set ε' to be determined later, and let the delta be . So if I show that I can find ε' for all ε>0 such that $|f(x)|ε'+|g(a)|ε'<ε$, I should be done with the proof since for $x∈(a-,a+), |f(x)-f(a)|<ε'$ and $|g(x)-g(a)|<ε'$.

$\begin{align}|f(x)|ε'+|g(a)|ε'=&|f(x)-f(a)+f(a)|ε'+|g(a)|ε'\\≤&[|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|]ε'+|g(a)|ε'\\=&[ε'+|f(a)|]ε'+|g(a)|ε'\\=&(ε')^2+[|f(a)|+|g(a)|]ε'\end{align}$

I can set $(ε')^2+[|f(a)|+|g(a)|]ε'=ε$, which by the quadratic formula yields $ε'=\frac{-|f(a)|-|g(a)|+\sqrt{[|f(a)|+|g(a)|]^2+4ε}}{2}$, since the other solution is negative.

So, what I think I have proven is that for all ε>0, I can find ε' with the corresponding  being such that $x∈(a-,a+)$ will lead to $|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|<ε$

Comment: This is also how I would prove it. The only mistake I noted was that you let $\delta'=\max(\delta_f,\delta_g)$. You need to take $\delta'=\min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$ since you want $(a-\delta',a+\delta')$ to be contained in both $(a-\delta_f,a+\delta_f)$ and $(a-\delta_g,a+\delta_g)$.

Comment: "...which by the quadratic formula yields" This is overkill. Doing analysis is very different from doing algebra.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: There is also somebody else's attempt for proving the same statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1901799/

Comment: @user1046533 I'll try to avoid doing so, I would hate to have to deal with a page of surds where it's not necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well There are few mistakes in your proof,
1.You need to prove $f(x)$ is bounded as a case and also take the case when either if $f(a)$,$g(a)$ are infinite.
2.Choose $\delta^{'}=\min({\delta_{f},\delta_{g}})$
Above everything it's a nice try!!!because you told you are a beginner so. Just fix these two points and also you need to be careful about doing the estimation of triangle inequality as mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: I would also add that the algebra is wrong in the estimate for $|f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(a)|$.  Specifically at the $\leq$ inequality, something went wrong: there shouldn't be $f(x)|f(x) - f(a)|$, but rather, $g(x)|f(x)-f(a)|$.

Comment: Wait let me see the whole proof again !!!

Comment: Yes Sir I overlooked that

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks, I'll try to be more careful next time.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what the problem with a bounded function is. Also, if a function attains values of infinity, doesn't it mean that it is discontinuous, which is not possible since f and g are continuous? Thanks for the correction about δ', though, I'll try to be more careful when typing questions in the future.

Comment: Lol be careful Function can take values at inifinity and still continuous f(x)=x is an example. Sorry to say you need to prove boundedness why? I suggest you to read real analysis as ur knowledge is still yet not perfect.Take g(x)=1/x (0,1) and f(x)=x in (0,1) and realise why bounded is needed thinking math is much more different that any other subject in the world.It's not physics or chemistry like you assume this and that and proceed which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\eps{\varepsilon}$You have had the idea, but writing a bit too much by trying to get "exact" $\eps$ and $\delta$ in various places. Also, the way you write the variables $\epsilon'$ and $\epsilon$ is confusing.

---

Here is a short proof that conceals most of the informal thoughts.

**Proof.** Let $\eps>0$. By continuity of $f$ and $g$ at $a$, let $\delta>0$ be such that for all $|x-a|<\delta$,
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|<\min\left(\frac{\eps}{|f(a)|+|g(a)|+1},1\right),\\
|g(x)-g(a)|<\min\left(\frac{\eps}{|f(a)|+|g(a)|+1},1\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|
&\le |f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(a)+f(x)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|\\
&\le |f(x)||g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)|\\
&\le \big(|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|\big)|g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)|\\
&\le \frac{|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|+|g(a)|}{1+|f(a)|+|g(a)|}\eps\le\eps
\end{align}
$$

Q.E.D.

---

Here are the thoughts in terms of semi-formal languages on how one comes up with the proof above.

Let $\eps>0$. You want to find $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|<\eps
$$
whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. You have realized that the key step is to estimate the left-hand side as
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|
&\le |f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(a)+f(x)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|\\
&\le |f(x)||g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)|\\
&\le \big(|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|\big)|g(x)-g(a)|+|g(a)||f(x)-f(a)|
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$
so that you can exploit the continuity of $f$ and $g$ to control the right-hand side.

If you let $\delta>0$ be such that for all $|x-a|<\delta$,
$$
|f(x)-f(a)|<\eps,\quad |g(x)-g(a)|<\eps\;,\tag{2}
$$
then (1) implies that
$$
|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|\le (\eps+|f(a)|+|g(a)|)\eps\tag{3}
$$
Since $\eps$ is arbitrary, this already *implies* the limit you want. (This is how analysis is done in practice: one does not try to get a "perfect" $\eps$ on the right-hand side.)

But if you really want the right-hand side to be "pretty" as $\eps$, you can adjust (2). For instance, you can let $\delta>0$ be such that for all $|x-a|<\delta$,
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)|<\min\left(\frac{\eps}{|f(a)|+|g(a)|+1},\eps,1\right),\\
|g(x)-g(a)|<\min\left(\frac{\eps}{|f(a)|+|g(a)|+1},\eps,1\right)\;,
\end{align}\tag{2'}
$$
which implies by (1) that
$$
|f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)|
\le \frac{|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|+|g(a)|}{1+|f(a)|+|g(a)|}\eps\le\eps\;.
$$

The idea here is that you can always adjust the right-hand side of (2') as small as you want by adding more (fixed) quantities in the "min" function. You do not need to solve a complicated quadratic equation to get the right $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about avoiding exact values where unnecessary. This proof is elegant, as well.

Comment: @Aqeel: you are welcome. If you find it useful, you can also "upvote" this answer.